# Prove that if $a>b$, then $a>2r$; let $r$ be the remainder of $a$ divided by $b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility

Overall this is intuitive and yet hard to proove.
I was thinking about demonstrating this starting from $a<2r$ until I get to a contradiction 
but I can't find one 
a small help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume $b > 0$.  I think this is false when $b<0$.

Definition of remainder is ...
$$
a = qb+r,\quad 0\le r < b .
$$
Now $b > 0$ so we conclude $q \ge 1$, since if $q=0$ then $a=r<b$, contrary to the assumption $a>b$.
So
$$
a=qb+r \ge 1\cdot b + r  > r + r = 2r .
$$

Answer (score 4):

For the reminder $r$ of $a$ divided by $b$ holds $0\le r\le b-1$ and $r\le a-b$, so summing them you get $2r\le a-1<a$